# Mailgun API - Curl connection fails because of unexpected eof while reading

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

I am struggling with an SSL error on a curl request to the Mailgun API for multiple hours. The weird thing here is: Only on this server do I have these problems:

```
curl -vvv 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/'

* Connected to api.eu.mailgun.net (34.111.145.192) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
* error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
```

curl Version

```
curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.14
Release-Date: 2022-01-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

I was already able to exclude the curl version as an error by spinning up a second server with exactly the same version and configuration - my hunch goes to some problems with certificates. When I run a `openssl s_client -connect api.eu.mailgun.net:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs` to check the connection this happens:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 320 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Server OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: No, that's definitely not related to 'certificates' -- in both cases the error is occurring at transport level long before the cert/chain is even sent much less validated, plus the chain from that host is valid.  It _might_ be due to something on the system like iptables/nftables although that doesn't usually wait until the second data frame; it might be something about the machine's environment, especially if it is virtual, or a container and not a machine at all; it mght be something about the network connection. But it's not programming and I wouldn't call it development.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 and my curl version is 7.81.0. I also tried compiling and installing a newer curl version, but the problem still persists. By the way, my server is a virtual cloud server hosted on Hetzner, is it the same for you?

Comment: Same problem here. `nc smtp.mailgun.org 25` doesn't show anything, tcpdump doesnt show any packets arriving. Is your VM in hel1 by any change? I'm recreating my stuff in fns1 to see if it related to that.
- Yeah, it seems to be a Helsinki thing, it's working in Falkenstein

Comment: Same problem here on Hetzner, Ubuntu with curl 7.81.0.

Comment: Answer added: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76566660/4880226
Some IP's was registrered as part of Iran, but not all. Shuffle the IP a few times (if it doesn't work the first time).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Change your IP by ordering a new one at the `Primary IP` page in the Hetzner Dashboard. If you're lazy and won't play around with your prod server, create a new VPS instead, check it with a few GEO IP services (use [iplocation.net](https://iplocation.net) and [ip-address-lookup-v4.com](https://ip-address-lookup-v4.com)). Hereafter SSH into your server, and execute the `curl -vvv 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/'` command. If things works as expected, turn off the new VPS, unassign the IP in the `Primary IP` dashboard, turn off your primary VPS, remove the current primary IP for your primary VPS, and assign the new and good ranked IP to your primary VPS. Turn off your primary VPS. Happy days. Please note that I personally has one IP which didn't show up as a IP from Iran, but it still failed. That why I suggest you to SSH into the new server, and double-check.

---

It's a problem with the location of the IP.

Yesterday I tried multiple version of curl, tracerouted a log, and debugged a few things. I even checked my IP's location at **a single** GEO-IP provider.

Hetzner answered my mail today, and told that some IP's has been flagged with a location in Iran. So I opened up another GEO-IP provider, and there was a match.

This service reported a location in Iran (Disclaimer: IP's not in used on my system anymore):
[ip-address-lookup-v4.com lookup for "91.107.209.182"](https://ip-address-lookup-v4.com/lookup.php?host=ip-address-lookup-v4.com&ip=91.107.209.182&x=0&y=0)

So I ordered another IP, turned of my VPS and changed the primary IP in the "Primary IPs" dashboard.

But that didn't fix things.

The following commands still ended up as the `eof while reading` or timeout.

But my IP was reported as located in Germany according to the following service: [ip-address-lookup-v4.com lookup for "49.12.73.102"](https://ip-address-lookup-v4.com/ip/49.12.73.102)

So.. I created yet another VPS, but Hetzner was so kind to provide me with the last provided IP. Well... Yet another VPS created. I simply created the VPS, logged into SSH and executed the `curl -vvv 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/'` command.

This time things worked as expected.

So I turned the new machine off, in `Primary IPs` I unassigned the IP. Hereafter I turned my primary VPS off, removed the bad IP, and assigned the new IP to my primary VPS. Lastly I removed the two test VPS'es and secured that no extra IP's was in the `Primary IPs` list.

I've not found service which flags 49.12.73.102 as a location in Iran, but let me know as a comment, if you find it.

Personally it's the first time I face this kind of problem from Hetzner. Luckly for me, it's a VPS. I cannot emagine how it would end up in a situation where the user has a dedicated instance.

If I was Hetzner, I'd consider to create a info-block at the top of the "Primary IP's" page, telling the user about the possible "wrong country" GEO-located IP... :-)

### For WordPress Users

For people with WordPress facing problems with Mailgun, I personally found the problem by installing the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin, where I noticed a curl error if I tried to sent a testmail with WP Mail SMTP. My plugin-page also locked up for 10+ secounds, so here I did the same thing, and noticed that my Oxygen plugin timed out after 10 secounds, where the request to Mailgun did result in a instant error.

Here's a few console results while I faced the problem, for people Googling this:

```
# curl -vvv 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/'
*   Trying 34.95.107.114:443...
* Connected to api.eu.mailgun.net (34.95.107.114) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
* error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
root@server-prod:~# 

# curl https://oxygenbuilder.com -iLv
*   Trying 35.230.4.135:443..
...
timeout (didn't save that for later)
```